# Why this program is not able to merge 2 Linked List in Sorted order?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a new sorted list. The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.

Example:

```
Input: 1->2->4, 1->3->4
Output: 1->1->2->3->4->4
```

```
class Solution {
 public:
  ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode* temp = l1;
    while(temp->next) {
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = l2;
            
    ListNode* a = l1;
    ListNode* b;
    while(a) {
      b = a->next->next;
      if (a->val >= a->next->val) {
        a->next->next = a;
        a->next = b;
      }
      a=a->next;
    }
    return l1;
  }
};
```

I am not able to figure out this error.

```
Line 27: Char 21: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:36:21
```

Comment: Question says to return a new sorted list, but you don't seem to be creating a new list anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop, you always assume that `a->next` is not null because you call `a->next->next`. However, `a->next` will be null when `a` points to the last element in the list.

Also, you appear to be trying to implement bubble sort, but that requires multiple iterations of the list to work properly. The input `10->20->30, 1->2->3` will not sort properly.